# No method declared with Objective-C selector

Tags: xcode, swift

Following some *excellent* advice given here, I handle `validateMenuItem` by comparing the menu items action to strings - that way you can change the tag or text of the menu and it still works. Well, until today, when the latest Xcode update spits out this error:

`No method declared with Objective-C selector 'toggleHidden'`

In this code...

```
override func validateMenuItem(menuItem: NSMenuItem) -> Bool {
    let c = selectedCards().count

    switch menuItem.action {
    case "toggleHidden": if c == 1 { if selectedCard()!.info["hidden"] ?? "false" == true { return true } else { return false } }
    case "toggleIgnore": if c == 1 { if selectedCard()!.info["ignore"] ?? "false" == true { return true } else { return false } }           
    default: return true
    }
    return true
}
```

The funny thing is, this is literally the next bit of code...

```
@IBAction func toggleHidden(sender: NSObject) {
     ...
}
```

Now I know that the items in `action` are actually selectors, so I tried this...

```
case Selector("toggleHidden"):
```

That compiles fine but returns the same error.

This was working fine before the update, does anyone have an idea why it might be spitting the error now?

Comment: Shouldn't it be "toggleHidden:"?

Comment: No, the ":" in the selector tells to send the sender as parameter with the method, correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: Sorry, so in this topic you are correct :) @Eiko

Comment: Ok this definitely changed for Swift 2.x.